# How to solve non-autonomous system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How I can start solving this non-autonomous system of ODEs ? Can I have any idea about nature of solution in prior as independent variable $\xi$ can be seen all the three ODEs as coefficient?

$15\,F\xi\,F_{{\xi}}+6\,{F}^{2}+10\,\xi\,G_{{\xi}}+8\,G+6\,F_{{\xi}}=0$

$5\,F\xi\,G_{{\xi}}+10\,G\xi\,F_{{\xi}}+8\,FG+10\,\xi\,H_{{\xi}}+12\,H+
6\,G_{{\xi}}=0$

$125\,{\xi}^{3}F_{{\xi,\xi,\xi}}-90\,F\xi\,H_{{\xi}}-180\,H\xi\,F_{{\xi
}}+750\,{\xi}^{2}F_{{\xi,\xi}}-180\,FH+830\,\xi\,F_{{\xi}}+80\,F-108\,
H_{{\xi}}=0$